# Stealing OAuth2 Tokens from IoT Devices

Tags: oauth

As I am delving into different forms of session authentication and persistence, I started to question how tokens are stored and the risk of a token being compromised. The scenario I have in mind is as follows:

A user has synced their smart phone to a social media account, and an OAuth2 token was granted. This token has an expiration time of three days from now. The user has left their phone either unlocked, or you have been able to compromise it briefly and obtain access to anything stored on the device (think the new Android media message exploit). In this time, you quickly grab the OAuth2 token and get out. You take this OAuth2 token and use it from your own device. Now for the next three days, you have authorization for the victims account.

My question - Is the last part feasible? If you can locate an OAuth2 token, can it be used from another device to grant authorization? What are preventative measures for this (other than encrypting OAuth tokens)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes stealing a stored OAuth token from a device and using it to make requests as the user will definitely work. OAuth access tokens are analogous to a traditional session cookie used in a web application. It might help if you're familiar with pre-http-only flag cross-site scripting vulnerabilities were an attacker would exploit a cross-site scripting vulnerability in a web application to steal the victims session cookies from the DOM then use the cookies to masquerade as the user. Most attacks against OAuth2 use a more direct route of exploiting a vulnerability in the providers OAuth2 flow that tricks the user into sending their OAuth token directly to the attacker. Egor Homakov and a handful of other folks have done a great job exploiting popular OAuth2 provider. Some Examples: [The Most Common OAuth2 Vulnerability](http://homakov.blogspot.com/2012/07/saferweb-most-common-oauth2.html) and [How we hacked Facebook with OAuth2 and Chrome bugs](http://homakov.blogspot.com/2013/02/hacking-facebook-with-oauth2-and-chrome.html).

Answer (score 1):

From http://oauthlib.readthedocs.org/en/latest/oauth2/clients/mobileapplicationclient.html:

> The implicit grant type does not include client authentication, and relies on the presence of the resource owner and the registration of the redirection URI. Because the access token is encoded into the redirection URI, it may be exposed to the resource owner and other applications residing on the same device.

As often, it depends on the server-side implementation and how it is being managed. See also:
[OAuth Open Redirector Attack](http://alexbilbie.com/2015/04/oauth-open-redirector-attack/)